# Synchronization of existing result set with database

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a server program that works with database and N clients that are connected to server. In database I have a table of persons with about 10 000 persons. Now on X client the following sql query is executed:

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE age >18 AND sex=1 ORDER BY age.
```

And ordered list of 2500 persons is shown to X client. If there are changes on server side then list of persons shown to X client must be updated in most effective way.

Now on server side person with id =120 was updated by some client. After this update we don't know his age and sex. So there are two situations:

1. His age >18 AND SEX=1 and he must be present in X client selected persons
2. His age <=18 OR SEX=2 and he mustn't be present in X client selected persons.

So what is the most effective way to find now out - if person with id=120 is in X selected persons or isn't? Is this person is, then what is its position? I consider here the easiest case, but what if there are three of five updates? What to do this case?

I think that there are solutions for such synchronization of existing result set with database if data change but I can't find necessary words to find it in internet. Please, any hints any solution/algorithm names.

Comment: Why not run the sql query again on X client, after any update/insert on person's table?

Comment: @Utsav Good question - because client dosn't load all data that can be in WHERE / ORDER by clauses. Besides there is too much data on server side.

Comment: In that case, may be you can first fetch last records among the 2500 records, every time your sql query runs. Now if for a new record on server side, if age>18 and sex=1, then compare the age with the last record. If greater, then skip else run the sql query again to adjust.